# jQuery: I need an antispam on my function

Tags: javascript, function, timeout, spam-prevention

I have a function which reveals a div in my nav when clicked, and you can toggle it, so it hides when you press it again.

The problem is, that you can spamclick it so the animation keeps going and breaks the div.

What I need is some kind of antispam click, I want it to wait until the first animation is done.

Here is the code:

```
$("#navDown").click(function(){
if($("#navExpand").height()===0){
    $('#navArrow').animateRotate(0, -180);
    $("#navExpand").animate({
        height: 150
    })
    $(".navExCon").delay(300).fadeToggle(150);
    }
else if($("#navExpand").height()===150)
    {
$(".navExCon").fadeToggle(150);
    $('#navArrow').animateRotate(180, 0);
    $("#navExpand").delay(300).animate({
        height: 0
    });
    };
```

});

UPDATE  /solution

This is what I did: 
note: it would be better with the use of color on this site, to see the changes.

```
$("#navDown").click("slow",function(){ // added time "slow": 600 u i think.
  if($("#navExpand").height()===0){
    $('#navArrow').animateRotate(0, -180);
    $("#navExpand").animate({
        height: 150
    },200)                    // added some time
    $(".navExCon").fadeToggle(100);
    }
    else if($("#navExpand").height()===150)
    {
    $(".navExCon").fadeToggle(250);
    $('#navArrow').animateRotate(180, 0);
    $("#navExpand").animate({
        height: 0
    },200);                  // added some time
    };
});
```

Comment: Its perfectly fine to post an actual answer to your own question and mark it as accepted, btw. You don't have to put it as an edit.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it indeed. This should not be in the body of your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a callback function when animation is finished:

```
var animating = false;
$("#navDown").click(function(){
    if (animating) {
        return; // Don't start new animation
    }
    animating = true;

    if($("#navExpand").height()===0){
        $('#navArrow').animateRotate(0, -180);
        $("#navExpand").animate({
            height: 150
        })
        $(".navExCon").delay(300).fadeToggle(150, function() {
            // Will be called after animation is finished
            animating = false;
        });
    }
    else if($("#navExpand").height()===150)
    {
        $(".navExCon").fadeToggle(150);
        $('#navArrow').animateRotate(180, 0);
        $("#navExpand").delay(300).animate({
            height: 0
        }, function() {
            // Will be called after animation is finished
            animating = false;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried with your sugestion, the click function does not seem to respond. However, after reading a little about callback i found a rather simple solution. It is in the update.